# Customizing the text reply

Tags: 8.1, call-sms-filter

How do I customize my rejecting call text message on my Windows Phone 8.1?

Answer (score 1):

Open the Phone app and tap on the three dots at the bottom of the screen. Tap settings then Edit replies. Here you can add and remove replies that you can send to rejected calls.